# Microsoft Office 2010 blocking files downloaded from the Internet

Tags: security, microsoft-office-2010

Ever since I installed Office 2010 I have to "unblock"(*) the documents/spreadsheets I download from Internet/mail. **How can I change that so I don't have to do that anymore?**

(*): right-click on the file -> properties -> Unblock

*Note: I don't know if the button says exactly 'Unblock', I use spanish Microsoft Office so it says "Desbloquear" on my pc.*

[image: screenshot]

---

**Edit:** I use Windows Vista Home Premium and Office 2010 Pro

Comment: Not an answer, but: you know why it does this, don't you? Because it really helps to prevent malicious attacks by blocking the automatic opening and running of documents which may contain malicious macros. Doesn't stop you doing it anyway, but is at least one layer of security more than you had before.

Comment: @Rory_Alsop I know why it does this. I just don't want it to do it; I know which dowloaded/emailed documents to open and which don't. I mean, I don't need that extra layer of security... my dad does, but I don't (and my dad doesn't touch my notebook)

Answer (score 2):

You do not say if you are using a Pro or home version, or what OS. This is not MS Office-related, but related to the Windows OS.

If you you have a Pro version, open gpedit.msc (this is not available in home version, but is easier to use) and go to:

User Configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Attachment Manager and enable the policy called "Do not preserve zone information in file attachments".

If you have home, go to this registry key:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments

and edit the value for key "SaveZoneInformation" to 2 .

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883260

Comment: I don't have an Attachments key under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\. I do have HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments key, but it doesn't have a SaveZoneInformation value.

Comment: @Toto You can add it system wide under the HKLM area, or make it just specific to you, and add the Attachments key under HKLU. In either case, in the right pane, right-click and add a 32-bit DWORD value and name it SaveZoneInformation (this is case sensitive, so cut and paste it). Then set the value to 2.

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly due to Microsoft Office, but is due to a new security setting in Windows which may have been installed as a kb patch during the install of Office.  By default now, when Windows downloads files from an "untrusted" source, it blocks those files on your local computer.  It can be a real pain, especially for zip archives.

Comment: Thanks @BBlake. Can I change that setting somewhere in Windows then?